# Polymer core-transition doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

I've been playing with Polymer for a few days and I want to do a menu, that will appear/disappear after clicking on the menu button. The problem is that I can't figure out why my code doesn't work.

Here it is:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

        <title>Title</title>

        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>

        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-icons/core-icons.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-menu/core-menu.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-meta/core-meta.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-item/core-item.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-transition/core-transition.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-media-query/core-media-query.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-shadow/paper-shadow.html">
        </style>
    </head>
    <body unresolved>   
        <core-header-panel flex>
            <paper-shadow z="1">
                <core-toolbar>
                    <paper-icon-button icon="menu" onclick="handleMenu()"></paper-icon-button>
                    <div flex>Project Management System</div>
                </core-toolbar>
            </paper-shadow>
        </core-header-panel>
        <div id="menu" class="core-menu">
            <core-item icon="settings" label="Settings"></core-item>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

and the Javascript

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
        console.log('Polymer Ready');
    });

    var meta;
    var transition;


    function handleMenu() {
        var menu = document.getElementById('menu');

            meta = document.createElement('core-meta');
            meta.type = 'transition';

            console.log(meta.list);
            console.log(transition);

            transition.teardown(menu);
            transition = getMeta().byId('core-transition-left');
            transition.setup(menu);
            transition.go(menu, true);

            console.log('Tap');
    }
</script>
```

When I click on the menu button an error will appear:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'teardown' of undefined

I've done everything as it was on demo page, I've been searching for the correct solution or some answers but nothing... does any one have an idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its not working because mainly your were missing the https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-transition/core-transition-css.html from the demo page.

After that the getMeta() method was also missing and the menu element needed to have the transition setup applied to it.

See and try the example below:

```js
   document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
     console.log('Polymer Ready');

     setup();

   });

   var meta;
   var transition;
   var state = {
     opened: false
   };

   function setup() {
     var target = document.getElementById('menu');

     if (transition) {
       transition.teardown(target);
     }

     transition = getMeta().byId('core-transition-left');
     transition.setup(target);
   }

   function getMeta() {
     if (!meta) {
       meta = document.createElement('core-meta');
       meta.type = 'transition';
     }
     return meta;
   }

   function handleMenu() {
     var target = document.getElementById('menu');
     state.opened = !state.opened;
     transition.go(target, state);
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>

<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-icons/core-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-menu/core-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-meta/core-meta.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-item/core-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-transition/core-transition.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-media-query/core-media-query.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-shadow/paper-shadow.html">


<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-transition/core-transition-css.html">

<body unresolved>

  <core-header-panel flex>
    <paper-shadow z="1">
      <core-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" onclick="handleMenu()"></paper-icon-button>
        <div flex>Project Management System</div>
      </core-toolbar>
    </paper-shadow>
  </core-header-panel>
  <div id="menu" class="core-menu">
    <core-item icon="settings" label="Settings"></core-item>
  </div>
```